# how to extract data in selenium python when all the class with similar name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook

I have most of the class name are same, i am not able to extract a specific information.

```
 <div class="block-record-info">
    <div class="title3">Author Information</div>
    <p class="FR_field">
    <span class="FR_label">Reprint Address: </span>
    Havens, T (reprint author)
    </p>
    <table class="FR_table_noborders" rules="NONE" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <p/>
    <p class="FR_field">
    <span class="FR_label">Addresses:   </span>
    </p>
    <table class="FR_table_noborders" rules="NONE" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <p/>
    </div>
    <div class="block-record-info">
    <div class="title3">Publisher</div>
    <p class="FR_field">
    <value>SOC JAPANESE STUD, UNIV WASHINGTON THOMSON HALL DR-05, SEATTLE, WA 98195 USA</value>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-record-info">
    <div class="title3">Categories / Classification</div>
    <p class="FR_field">
    <span class="FR_label">Research Areas:</span>
    Area Studies; Asian Studies
    </p>
    <p class="FR_field">
    <span class="FR_label">Web of Science Categories:</span>
    Area Studies; Asian Studies
    </p>
    </div>
```

i want output like this

```
Publisher 

SOC JAPANESE STUD, UNIV WASHINGTON THOMSON HALL DR-05, SEATTLE, WA 98195 USA
Research Areas

Area Studies; Asian Studies

Web of Science Categories

Area Studies; Asian Studies
```

how do i get it?

Comment: There are several occurrences of `<div class="title3">`, but the one you want has the specific text `Publisher`, so you should be able to find it easily.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the output you want by following the approach mentioned below.

**Code:**

```
# Print the "Publisher" text.
print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='block-record-info']/div[@class='block-record-info'][1]/div").text

# Print the other paragraph text which you have specified in your output.

records = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="block-record-info"]/div[@class="block-record-info"]')

for record in records:
print record.find_element_by_xpath('.//p').text
```